# boots and sits at grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2

To Reinstall Grub:

Tried the below first.

To add boot-repair to the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Once Installation completes, run boot-repair on terminal by typing the following command or select it by System → Administration → Boot Repair.

```
boot-repair
```

I just tried the above but it still went to back to the prompt grub rescue. I have booted the machine with the live CD and used terminal to unmount the drive then remount it, tried to reinstall Grub 2. No change.
 It all started when i did the daily update of Ubuntu. It asked me to reboot and it went to grub rescue. My main problem is that there is no other operating system on the laptop. I tried to install mint over it but it failed, Tried a repair install, failed. At this I've working at it for at least 24hrs straight. I'm fed up with it.

Any suggestion would be gratefully appreciated.

```
 Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 23Dec2013]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 94 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 13.10 
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   970,498,047   970,496,000  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         970,500,094   976,771,071     6,270,978   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         970,500,096   976,771,071     6,270,976  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001   ext4       
/dev/sda5        6ea1bfcc-32d4-4dd7-933f-2212b03fc6a7   swap       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 i386

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 45,51,53; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001' {
recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic root=UUID=1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-12-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-12-generic-advanced-1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-12-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic root=UUID=1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-12-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-12-generic-recovery-1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-12-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic root=UUID=1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=6ea1bfcc-32d4-4dd7-933f-2212b03fc6a7 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-aJQfGocR/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
File descriptor 9 (/proc/5945/mounts) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 13205: bash
  No volume groups found

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2014-02-18__23h59 ===================
boot-repair version : 3.199~ppa40~saucy
boot-sav version : 3.199~ppa40~saucy
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa47~saucy
boot-sav-extra version : 3.199~ppa40~saucy
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 13.10, saucy, Ubuntu, i686)
ls: cannot access /home/usr/.config: No such file or directory
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-gnome.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash -- maybe-ubiquity

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda1:Ubuntu 13.10 (13.10):Ubuntu:linux

=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 i386" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sda1: UUID="1d5bd5d8-4e90-43ae-95cf-91e881c25001" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="6ea1bfcc-32d4-4dd7-933f-2212b03fc6a7" TYPE="swap"


1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 0 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

=================== sda1/etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Oct 17 00:52 grub.d
total 72
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7850 Oct 10 17:53 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5949 Aug 15  2013 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11479 Oct 10 17:53 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10258 Oct 10 17:53 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1798 Jun 17  2013 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11531 Oct 10 17:53 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1426 Oct 10 17:53 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct 10 17:53 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Oct 10 17:53 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Oct 10 17:53 README




=================== sda1/etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"



=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not EFI-compatible.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc ,   update-grub,    32, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA ST9500420ASG (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  497GB  497GB   primary   ext4            boot
2      497GB   500GB  3211MB  extended
5      497GB   500GB  3211MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ-840S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 4700MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      131kB  3674MB  3674MB  primary               boot, hidden

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST9500420ASG;
1:1049kB:497GB:497GB:ext4::boot;
2:497GB:500GB:3211MB:::;
5:497GB:500GB:3211MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

BYT;
/dev/sr0:4700MB:scsi:2048:2048:msdos:MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ-840S;
1:131kB:3674MB:3674MB:::boot, hidden;


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu-gnome)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type ext4 (rw)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  agpgart autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency disk dri ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse fw0 hpet input kmsg log lp0 mapper mcelog mem net network_latency network_throughput null parport0 port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda5 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout tpm0 uinput urandom vga_arbiter vhost-net zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  1.5G  188M  1.3G  13% /
udev           devtmpfs   1.5G   12K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      303M  1.1M  302M   1% /run
/dev/sr0       iso9660    876M  876M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   843M  843M     0 100% /rofs
none           tmpfs      4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs      1.5G   28K  1.5G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      1.5G   84K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs      100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1      ext4       456G  3.1G  430G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00036ad0

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   970498047   485248000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       970500094   976771071     3135489    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       970500096   976771071     3135488   82  Linux swap / Solaris



=================== Recommended repair
Recommended-Repair
This setting will reinstall the grub2 of sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/etc/default/grub

*******lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a2] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:30aa]
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a6] (rev 03)
*******

grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-19ubuntu2,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda1 into the MBR of sda
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.
```

Comment: according to comment on answer, this problem somehow went away...

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do

1) Boot with the live CD

2) Open terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l` for determining the partition with the Ubuntu installation, in your case it is **/dev/sda1**

3) Mount the partition containing the Ubuntu installation.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

4) Run the *grub-install* command

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

5) Reboot

6) Refresh the GRUB menu with `sudo update-grub`

Comment: i had tried that option twice...same result. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. I have resolved the problem now, by wiping the hd using particion magic.. See solution above